# Input Binding CommandParameter Bind to Window

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I want to have a window level KeyBinding with command paramter as window itself.

e.g.

```
<KeyBinding Command="{Binding CloseCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=mainWindow}" Key="Esc"/>
```

Binding works, but paramter comes in as null. What's the work around?

Following is my Command:`

```
public class DelegateCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;
    private readonly Action<object> _execute;

    public DelegateCommand(Action<object> execute)
        : this(execute, null)
    {
    }

    public DelegateCommand(Action<object> execute,
                   Predicate<object> canExecute)
    {
        if (execute == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Action excute is null");
        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    [DebuggerStepThrough]
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute == null ? true : _canExecute(parameter);
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _execute(parameter);
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }
```

Comment: What kind of `Command` you are using?

Comment: Does your `Window` has a name and how does your command look like? And because I'm snoopy: why do you want to use the window as a parameter? What are you wanna do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually this working for me - but i am using the `RelayCommand<FrameworkElement>` of [MVVM Light Toolkit[1](https://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/).

```
<Window.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Command="{Binding MyCommand, ElementName=MainRoot}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=MainRoot}" Key="Esc"/>
</Window.InputBindings>
```

In my case the `Command` comes from a `DependencyProperty`, but that shouldn't make a big difference.

```
public RelayCommand<FrameworkElement> MyCommand
{
    get { return (RelayCommand<FrameworkElement>)GetValue(MyCommandProperty); }
    set { SetValue(MyCommandProperty, value); }
}

// Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for MyCommand.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
public static readonly DependencyProperty MyCommandProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("MyCommand", typeof(RelayCommand<FrameworkElement>), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(null));




public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    MyCommand = new RelayCommand<FrameworkElement>(DoSthYo);
}

public void DoSthYo(FrameworkElement fwE)
{
    var x = fwE; 
}
```

So because this is working - i think its your `Command` that does not support `CommandParameter` maybe.

Comment: Edited my Q to include the command, going to try your implementation, I am not using MVVM Toolkit.

Comment: Maybe https://github.com/paulcbetts/mvvmlight/blob/dce4e748c538ed4e5f5a0ebbfee0f54856f52dc6/V3/GalaSoft.MvvmLight/GalaSoft.MvvmLight%20(NET35)/Command/RelayCommandGeneric.cs gives you a hint.

Comment: This is interesting, actully my command directly on Button for example, picks up the element binding as CommandParameter .e.g following work, Inputbinding doesn't 

<Button Content="Close" Width="100" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Command="{Binding CloseCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=mainWindow}"/>

Comment: Works! Thanks, RelativeSource with my Command example din't - What's the difference?

Comment: Maybe because `Window` itself looking for a `Window` as parent. Because the `KeyBinding` is directly under `Window`.

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to use a `RelativeSource` in your `CommandParameter` binding:

```
<Window.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Command="{x:Static local:CloseWindowCommand.Instance}" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}" Key="Esc" />
</Window.InputBindings>
```

In this way your binding can be independant from the name of your `Window`.
Then you can create a `static` command for closing each window of your application:

```
public class CloseWindowCommand : ICommand
{
    public static readonly ICommand instance = new CloseWindowCommand();
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    private CloseWindowCommand()
    {
    } 

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return (parameter is Window);
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        Window win;
        if (CanExecute(parameter))
        {
            win = (Window)parameter;
            win.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

I hope it can help you.